# Does the new XIB format in Xcode 5 lose app backward compatibility?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, interface-builder, xcode5

So, Xcode 5 has this new XIB format, which if you convert an old project to use that format, you can no longer open that XIB file in previous versions of Xcode.

I was wondering if I were to convert my project to use the new XIB format, will it effect the compatibility of the app? Whether it was a Mac or iOS app, will it still run on previous versions of iOS/Mac (prior iOS7/MacOS 10.9)?

Comment: It won't affect application compatibility - just Xcode compatibility

Comment: @powerj1984 Great, that's an answer actually, not just a comment. If you could provide a link, too, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't affect application compatibility - just Xcode compatibility.

I don't really have any link to back this up, just my personal experience using the latest Xcode betas.

Comment: One wouldn't expect a link, since Xcode 5 is still under NDA.

Comment: @JWWalker I strongly believe there is this super curious guy out there who saw this new format and did a whole set of experiments and wrote a post about it. It's just amazing how backward compatibility is preseved.. Does the XIB gets converted back to the old format when packaged? Or perhaps there is some other trickery we are not aware of?

Comment: @Mazyod, xib files have always been converted to nib format when packaging, presumably for compatibility.  But I haven't checked whether that has changed in Xcode 5.